# How to retrieve point location data from a WMS leaflet layer?

Tags: r, web-scraping, leaflet, maps

I am very new to working with maps and was given a task to collect data on points from this website: https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es/exovi_externo/CargarMapaFosas.htm#

So far I have managed to figure out how to load the map and one of the layers:

```
library("leaflet")
library("leaflet.extras")
library("shiny")

x.WGS=-3.87988
y.WGS=40.26270
leaflet() %>% setView(x.WGS, y.WGS, zoom = 5) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addWMSTiles(
    baseUrl = "https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es/geoserver/wms",
    layers = "INTERVENIDA",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE), attribution = "")
```

But I am a bit stuck on how I can get point information from this. Can someone help? As far as I understand the shiny package should be useful here but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You're fetching **images** from a [WMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) endpoint, which contain graphical little flags, and no machine-readable data at all. Compare with e.g. [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) or [vector tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_tiles), protocol stacks which serve similar purposes but allow access to the raw(er) geographical features.

That said: there are some tricks that can be applied to *this particular WMS endpoint*. If you have a good look at the [XML of the `GetCapabilities` document for that endpoint](https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS), you'll notice that you can ask the WMS endpoint to provide you the images in several formats, e.g. `image/png` or `image/jpeg`; but this particular endpoint provides non-image formats such as `application/rss+xml` (AKA GeoRSS).

So if you take one of the request URL in the OpenLayers viewer, change `image/png` with `application/rss+xml`, and make a manual request to the WMS endpoint, like...

```
https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=PROSPECTADA&SRS=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/rss+xml&TRANSPARENT=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&BBOX=-10.12451171875,34.287109375,5.12451171875,45.712890625&WIDTH=694&HEIGHT=520
```

...then you'll get back a well-formed, parseable XML document which looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0"><channel>    <title>exovi:OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA</title><description>Generated from exo2</description><link><![CDATA[https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms?service=wms&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&format=application%2Frss+xml&layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&styles=prospectada&height=520&width=694&transparent=true&bbox=-10.12451171875%2C34.287109375%2C5.12451171875%2C45.712890625&srs=EPSG%3A4326]]>    </link><atom:link href="https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms?service=wms&amp;request=GetMap&amp;version=1.1.1&amp;format=application%2Frss+xml&amp;layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&amp;styles=prospectada&amp;height=520&amp;width=694&amp;transparent=true&amp;bbox=-10.12451171875%2C34.287109375%2C5.12451171875%2C45.712890625&amp;srs=EPSG%3A4326" rel="self"/><item><title>OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4def</title><link><![CDATA[https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms/reflect?featureid=OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4def&layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&format=application%2Fatom%2Bxml]]></link><guid><![CDATA[https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms/reflect?featureid=OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4def&layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&format=application%2Fatom%2Bxml]]></guid>         <description><![CDATA[<h4>OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA</h4>
<ul class="textattributes">
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">CARTOGRAFICA_UTM_ID</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">177</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">FOSA_NM</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">186/2009 ASTU</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">FOSA_ID</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">186</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">DENOMINACION_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Fosa en la Avda. de Oviedo, hacia el nº 28</span></li>

<li><strong><span class="atr-name">LOCALIDAD_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Noreña</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">PROVINCIA_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Asturias</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">LOCALIDAD_ALTERNATIVA_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Noreña</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">RAZON_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">FUSILAMIENTO</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">FOSA_ESTADO_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">DESAPARECIDA</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">ESTADO_ACTUAL_FOSA_TX</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">BAJO CONSTRUCCIÓN</span></li>
<li><strong><span class="atr-name">NUM</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">0</span></li>
</ul>
]]></description><georss:point>43.394316667 -5.706486111</georss:point></item>    <item><title>OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4df0</title><link><![CDATA[https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms/reflect?featureid=OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4df0&layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&format=application%2Fatom%2Bxml]]></link><guid><![CDATA[https://mapadefosas.mjusticia.es:443/geoserver/wms/reflect?featureid=OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA.fid--343d670c_171b1be4379_4df0&layers=exovi%3AOV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA&format=application%2Fatom%2Bxml]]></guid><description><![CDATA[<h4>OV_VISTA_4326_PROSPECTADA</h4>
```

You should then be able to pipe that through a XML or GeoRSS parser and transform your data as desired. Depending on your skillset and tools, you might want to try other non-image format. There is no need to work with Leaflet at all if you can just download the data.

---

(Please note that that particular endpoint offers data in GeoRSS format *at the time of this writing*, and that other WMS endpoints may or may not provide non-image formats, as configured by their administrators)